# Replace if else statement with a branchless code

Tags: c++, vector

I have code like below:

```
    if(a[i]==b[j])
    {
     vect1.push_back(i);
     vect2.push_back(j);
    }
```

How can i rewrite the above statement without using if else in c++.

Thank you!!!

Comment: Pardon me, but where's `else`?

Comment: Why?  the code is perfectly readable as is, and if you change it to be more "clever", the readability will likely suffer.  Performance can't be the reason unless you have profiled results that shows some branching effect that is causing performance degradation.

Comment: `(void)((cond) && (exp,exp,0));` Nicely obfuscated now. (No `if` in the source, but that does not buy you anything).

Comment: There is no else part. I just want to replace the if part for checking wtherer my overall code is faster or not

Comment: If you are able to get any noticeable improvement I would be very very very very surprised.

Comment: @Deduplicator... Please put ur reply in answer so that it will be useful to many....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really must not use `if`, likely for some contest, there's of course a way.
Still, even though it looks branchless, there's likely a branch in the compiled code.

I count it as obfuscation, but anyway, here goes:

```
if(cond) {
    expr1;
    expr2;
}
```

Can be written as:

```
(void)((cond) && (expr1,expr2,0));
```

**Don't use it**, beside possibly in some anyway obscure preprocessor-hackif nothing else will do, or whoever must use it later (including you) will get mighty disgruntled.

Comment: How is this branchless?

Comment: @FDinoff: It it not really branchless. Though it might be slightly likelier to lead to branchless executable-code, if the expressions allow.

Comment: @Deduplicator why would it be slightly likelier to lead to branchless executable-code? If anything, code obfuscation is more likely to decrease optimization opportunities that the compiler might find.

Comment: @ComeRaczy: It might, or it might not. That depends an awful lot on the exact implementation you work with, and is not neccessarily really accessible to sane logic without delving into the compiler's details and the compiler-writer's mind. Also, this obfuscation is not too bad seen with compiler-eyes.