# Ternary Conditional Operator for C++ vectors

Tags: c++

I have a code where i use the ternary operator. I want the vector to perform push_back only if c>d. Else, nothing should happen. How can I implement this. But i should not use if else conditions. Below is my code:

```
    int c=30,d=10;
    std::vector<int> first;
    (c>d) ? first.push_back(c) : "What should be here";
```

Comment: `(c > d) ? first.push_back(c) : void();` It's far better to use `if`.

Comment: I know that... But my requirement is this

Comment: use of void is making the program to get stuck

Comment: @vinodchelladurai no , it isn't: [**see it live**](http://ideone.com/IPHs8I), its the *rest* of your program you're not showing us that is "stuck".

Comment: i mean program is stopping while running

Comment: I confirm that this works perfectly ! @T.C. if you add it as an answer and explain the void(), i'll upvodte !

Comment: @vinodchelladurai : you should use ternary operator only for embedding conditionals in a more complex expression (and with expreme care due to its precedence vis-avis && || and `<<`)

Comment: Related to these two questions by this user: [Replace if else statement with a branchless code](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25814710/3614835), [Optimize the C++ code through removal of branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25828968/optimize-the-c-code-through-removal-of-branches)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector`'s `push_back` returns `void`. If one of the last two operands of a conditional operator is of type `void` and isn't a `throw` expression, then both must have type `void`. Hence:

```
(c > d) ? first.push_back(c) : void();
```

Of course, this is by far less readable and actually more verbose than

```
if (c > d) first.push_back(c);
```

and shouldn't be used in actual code.

Comment: I agree. IMHO the conditional operator should only be used to reproduce a value depending on a condition but not for any side effects.